# 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to run "mvn install" , but getting this error as below

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/spring/platform/platform-bom/1.1.3.RELEASE/platform-bom-1.1.3.RELEASE.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact
```

i am using the petclinic code from https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/blob/master/pom.xml

Please help me where I am stuck while running this code
I am new to Jenkins and Maven as well.

Comment: First, you need to post the exact log you have (what you posted is incomplete). Second, are you behind a proxy?

Comment: yes i am inside my organisation. I am unable to post exact log here

Comment: [ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not transfer artifact io.spring.platform:platform-bom:pom:1.1.3.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Temporary failure in name resolution @ line 51, column 25 [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.servlet.jsp:javax.servlet.jsp-api:jar is missing. @ line 73, column 21
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for javax.servlet.jsp.jstl:javax.servlet.jsp.jstl-api:jar is missing. @ line 85, column 21

Comment: i could add few more lines

Comment: Then you need to configure Maven about this proxy: see [this](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html)

Comment: i added proxy, but still its throwing same error. Could you provide any other solution?